# How to check the vote of my delegate?

Tags: voting, delegating

My delegate announced on Twitter its intention for the coming vote. This corresponds to what I would have chosen.

How will I be able to check after the vote that my delegate voted as announced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tzscan offers this as an extra information on anyone’s address.

See an example [here](https://tzscan.io/tz1NortRftucvAkD1J58L32EhSVrQEWJCEnB?default=vote).

Answer (score 1):

Kukai give a list of vote for many delegates with their number of rolls but it offers less guaranty of perenity than Tzscan. 
https://kukai.app/bakers-list